# List returns only the last value

Tags: c#, list

I have summarized the problem with below example.

```
static List<double> values = new List<double>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        doThis();
        foreach (var value in values)
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    public static void doThis()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            double value = 0;
            double sum = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                value = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
                sum += value;
            }
            values.Add(sum / 10);
        }
    }
```

With this code, values list returns the same value for all indexes.
values =  {rnd , rnd, rnd, rnd..., rnd}. Somehow, at the end last value overwrites others.

However, if I debug step by step, it shows different values:  values = {rnd0, rnd1, rnd2 ...., rnd99}.

I appreciate if you enlighten me.

Comment: You need to lock your random generator

Comment: Although this is a dup, explaining the apparently inconsistent behavior when simply running the code or debugging it is worthwile. The problem is `Random rnd = new Random();` inside your outer loop. `DoThis` executes blindingly fast so you are creating over and over again a `Random` instance with the same seed (timestamp by default). This makes your `rnd`s generate the same sequence every time. This doesn't happen when you debug because `DoThis` stops being fast and starts being absurdly slow as you inspect values on each outer iteration.

Comment: have look to my answer ..also my blog post will give you more detail on this...

Comment: I get it now, thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a single, unique `Random`. If you create multiple instances in a short amount of time, they are likely to return the *same* sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I did experiment with it have look to blogpost : [Random Number in MultiThreading](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/03/random-number-in-multithreading_7.html)

Random() – it make use of system clock as seed value and create instance.
As random make use of System clock as input when creating two instances as below

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        Random rand1 = new Random();
```

It use same system clock input so output of above when doing below code

```
        Console.WriteLine(rand.Next());
        Console.WriteLine(rand1.Next());
```

generate same random number. Example both line of code write same vlaue on console.

**Solution for resolving random issue :**

Keep random function out

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double value = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            value = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
            sum += value;
        }
        values.Add(sum / 10);
    }
```

answer is if you try in multithreading scenario , there is chance of failing again

For example

```
   var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> dothis());
   var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> dothis());

   public static void doThis()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            double value = 0;
            double sum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                value = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
                sum += value;
            }
            values.Add(sum / 10);
        }
    }
```

if one try like this then (1) case i given my answer also fails , as both thread create `Random` with same seed value.

Comment: One question. Why would you ever do 2 and 3 when 1 is inexpensive and easy?

Comment: @InBetween - if you go and execute that method in multiple thread than you land in same issue again...have look to blogpost i attached in my answer ..i tried it with the multiple threads ..and in that case first one fails (when two thread call method )

Comment: @InBetween - updaed my answer ...

Comment: if I'd need this in any multithreading environment I'd probably use a outer `Random` provider to begin with. But in any case, I'd use option 1 with a thread specific seed (current timestamp + threadId or whatever)... There is still no justification in keeping `rnd` inside the outer loop.

Comment: @InBetween - yes you can do that ..i provide that thing in my blogpost too..in detail..in you can create Random before creating task and pass that as method argument it will work

Comment: More comprehensive explanation in different cases like multithreading... I like it.

Comment: I'm not discussing your blog post, I'm discussing the code you've provided in your answer and I have yet to see the reason why in options 2 and 3, `Random rnd = new Random();` inside the outer loop is a good idea, be it in single or multi threaded environments. I might be missing something here, I'd be glad to understand it.

Comment: @InBetween - try the way calling method in multi threading senario ...you will get the answer ...like this var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> dothis());
   var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> dothis());...if get same value i like you to rever -1

Comment: @InBetween - i extended answer to multithreading scenario that and provided good information ...that is the point of putting -1 ???

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. In option 3 if you move `Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());` *outside the outer loop* everything works well too. No need of sleeps, *you already have a guaranteed unique seed on every call*! And if the previous solution is valid, why would you ever do option 2?

Comment: @InBetween - my answer also explain things in detail..which not given in top rated answer....i think you agree on that

Comment: @InBetween - i provided three solution and its on you ,,, you can go for best one you like it ...the whole point in putting Thread.sleep() is to get different seed value from the clock when creating Random ... that all i can say

Comment: @InBetween -  in  my answer i given reason why Random gives you same vlaue ..its beause it taking same seed value that is from system clock..is that writting in top rated answer here ...you do -1 if someone give you good information , thats good

Comment: *its beause it taking same seed value that is from system clock*. What seed are you taking from the system clock in `Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());` in option 3? Please tell me, I'm curious to know.

Comment: @InBetween - Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode() create new guid every time and it seed getHashcode of that guid ..why dont you try out at your end ?? if two thread go at same time it will give you new seed value each time ...that is the point

Comment: @InBetween - this is also one way new Random(new System.DateTime().Millisecond).Next(); to seed random with different value

Comment: Exaclty! Then why is `Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())` inside the outer loop? And why, oh why, is there a `Thread.Sleep(50);` to boot!

Comment: @InBetween -  
at point 3. if you are taking about Thread.Sleep(50); Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()); then its mistake ..i updated it ...i copy pased above code and forget to remove Thread.Sleep(50); that is done now...i hope you like to revert your -1

Comment: @InBetween - if that is case then Apologies ...I misunderstood you..sorry again...

Comment: No its not done, `Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())` is still inside the outer loop when its totally unecessary and wasteful. And once you put it outside the outer loop where it belongs, give me one single reason why you would ever do option 2.

Comment: @InBetween - try out this at your machine and let me know var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> dothis());
   var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> dothis());

   public static void doThis()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            double value = 0;
            double sum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                value = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
                sum += value;
            }
            values.Add(sum / 10);
        }
    } , what you get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161021/discussion-between-inbetween-and-pranay-rana).

Comment: @InBetween - Why one whould need case 2 and 3 ?

answer is if you try in multithreading scenario , there is chance of failing again